# How to select specific values from list of arrays using LINQ

Tags: vb.net

I have a measures from Power Analzyzer stored as two dimensional array. Single measure has 18 parameters. So when I have 4 measures they are stored in `array(3)(17)`.

What I want to do is select from this array values that have unique number of one parameter. Next I want select from them this one that has highest value of another parameter.

I copy data from this array to new list of array so I can use `LINQ`.
But I have troubles writing correct `LINQ` request. Below I write my request in pseudocode, so you will be know what I want to do. I have multiple group of measures(11) values and there is maybe way to automatic do this for each group.

```
    dim Query = from values in measures
                where measures(11) is equal in all query and
                where is max value of measures(2)
                select values
```

For example below are 3 measures:

```
    measure no1: (value(1), value(2), ...value(11), .. value(18))
    measure no2: (value(1), value(2), ...value(11), .. value(18))
    measure no3: (value(1), value(2), ...value(11), .. value(18))
```

so I have `array(2)(17)`. Typically I have hundreds or thousands of measures.

All values are integers, value 2 is voltage, value 11 is measure ID. Sometimes measures have the same ID. In that case Analyzer tells that those measures are applying to the same event, so I want to choose from them this one that have highest recorded value in value (2).

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you are asking.. If you could provide an example of the data (preferably in a table format) showing what you would like to select it would be extremely helpful to anyone trying to help

Answer (score 0):

So I worked out what you meant (I think).

Try this:

```
Dim maxResultsPerById = measures.GroupBy(Function(x) x(idVal)).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x(voltageVal)).Select(Function(x) x.First())
```

Just replace `voltageVal` and `idVal` with their corresponding indexes.

This groups all the measures by ID, and then sorts them in descending order by voltage, selecting the first of each as an integer array.

Comment: Seems to works! But i dont understand this code, especially those function x statements.

Comment: This is the extension method version of LINQ, which I prefer to use. `Function(x)` is an 'Anonymous Method', `x` being whatever collection you are performing the function on. So `GroupBy()` will take your `List(Of Integer())` as `x` and group it by the ID value. The parameter doesn't have to be named `x`, it can be whatever you want it to be.